# JavaCPP - how to actually generate the C++ JNI wrappers?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native, javacpp

I'm trying to use JavaCPP to create java bindings for some C++ library. The process has 2 aspects

- A linux shared library (.so) needs to be built, containing the native entry points (JNIEXPORT). It so happens my library is header-only so I just pass the includes to JavaCPP
- A java class needs to be generated with methods using the "native" keyword, whose signatures correspond to those on the native side

The Java "properties" file (the part which describes how to build the .so and how to generate the Java file) looks like this:

```
@Properties(
    //target = "Client",  // NOTE: with this commented, .so gets built; with it enabled, Java class gets written
    value = @Platform(
        includepath = {"jnigen/src/main/cpp/mpf"},
        include = "ClientWrapper.hpp"
    )
)
public class Mpf implements InfoMapper {
    public void map(InfoMap infoMap) {
        infoMap.put(new Info("mpf::ClientWrapper").pointerTypes("Client"));
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't for the life of me generate the C++ bindings. I know because the .so doesn't contain the entry points, looking at it with `nm -D X.so`. If I specify a "target" property the Java class gets outputted, which **does** look good, but no `.so`. If I leave out `target` property, the .so is successfully built, but **it has no bindings**. I also see it hasn't got them, by passing -nodelete to the `java -jar javacpp.jar` so it keeps the generated cpp files - they only have marshalling code inside and not my stuff (one class).

The JavaCPP documentation is a nightmare, and the steps are so entagled I can't work it out. Suggestions for alternative libraries are also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The command for generating the JNI headers is `javah` did you run that? I think your java version might be relevant to the answer. here's the [tutorial](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/stepbystep/index.html) I used in early 2017. Thank google for saving all my history. I'm using java 8

Comment: I know about `javah` (or `javac -h`) but I was under the impression JavaCPP would do this for you, since it parses the C++ project and generates the Java side of things. Running javah would be the easier things it does.

Comment: Oh and you tutorial doesn't have to do with the JavaCPP library, it's barebone JNI (which I'm switching to).

Answer (score 2):

The new [Mapping Recipes for C/C++ Libraries](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/wiki/Mapping-Recipes) wiki page should clarify all this, but let me know if there is still anything unclear, and I will provide additional precisions here.

In this case, we could call JavaCPP on `Mpf` with the `@Properties(target="Client", ...)` value set, creating a class called `Client`, so the series of commands would look like this:

```
$ javac -cp javacpp.jar Mpf.java
$ java -jar javacpp.jar Mpf
$ javac -cp javacpp.jar Client.java
$ java -jar javacpp.jar Client
```